# pop up AlertBuild.Dialog just once from the Service class

Tags: android

I am sending data `route,long, lat, mac` to the Server very 10 seconds. Often the `route` is `0`. In this case, the server will be asked for the route. As soon as the app has the route from the server , Checkbox AlertDialog  appears to confirm the result by the user. Then the `route` will be envloped with the other data `Long, lat, mac` as JSOn string and transmitted to the server again.

I am facing Problem that the alert Dialogs will pile up when the user does not interact with the Dialog immediatly. What I am trying to achieve is to pop up the Dialog window just once when the server provides the app with `route` and not very 10 seconds with the Response from the server since when the user reacts too late he has to confirm all these Dialog Windows also after 1 Minute he has to confirm 6 Dialog Windows.

After starting the service from the MainActivity, the Dialog window in my case pops up from the Service class with the help of `lert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`

I appreciate any help.

my popup_stop method in the Service class:

```
private void stop_popup(final ArrayList<Integer> routeList) {


        int routeListSize = routeList.size();

        if (routeListSize > 0) {

            String[] charSequence = new String[routeList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < routeList.size(); i++) {
                charSequence[i] = String.valueOf(routeList.get(i));
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


            builder.setTitle("Has this route arrived the stop? ");

            builder.setMultiChoiceItems(charSequence, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

        route_number = routeList.get(which);

                                                                }    
                        }
                    });

            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you want to achieve??

Comment: I want to starts it  once when the route is known and not evry 10 seconds.

Comment: What do you mean by "route is known"...if it is any boolean value or an object then you can use simple if condition....

Comment: `route` is int value when it is known the Dialog Windows Pops up as Long as it is known. I am already checking whether is it null or not in the onPostExecute() method that is not the Problem. The Problem is when it is know.